# Design a super decoder using logic gates

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, circuit, boolean-algebra

[Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELN8i.png)

I need to design a decoder using the table given and logic gates. I dont need a complete solution but an approach or headstart on this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick tips when reading the table:

A = E

B = E

C = E and Q2

D = E and (Q1 or Q2)

E = E

F = E and Q1 and Q2

G = not C

This is not the only solution; it is also possible to use variable Q0.

It is a bit strange to have a variable and an output named E.